# Test website when CDN does not load

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, testing, http-status-code-404, web-development-server

I want to test what a website will look like if certain resources (from a CDN) do not load. I'm using Chrome and/or Firefox developer tools to test. What can I do to simulate a domain being down/blocked?

I would like to be able to compare windows with and without the domain loaded side by side on separate monitors or be able to enable/disable the domain and reload quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line that loads the resource?

If you don't have code access block the CDN in a firewall/proxy.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I could modify the hosts file to redirect the domain. However, I was hoping for a more temporary solution that could be applied on a per-window/tab basis, hence the request for a Chrome and/or Firefox solution.

Comment: You might want to edit your question as it reads: "What can I do to simulate a domain being down/blocked?" I usually look to fiddler to do that kind of stuff.

Comment: I'm not well versed in Fiddler, so if there is a temporary solution using it, that might work.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-block-url's-using-fiddler-proxy. It is as temporary as the config lasts ;) Warning: once you start using Fiddler you will become addicted ;)

Comment: I had to setup HTTPS decryption: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

After that, the Fiddler method seemed to work OK in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I guess this solution will do for now. If you want to post it as the answer, I'll be happy to apply it.